# Access Denied issue when connecting to XERO using oAuth2.0

Tags: vb.net, oauth-2.0, xero-api

I am creating an application that will allow a user to send Invoices from a local database application to XERO.

Connection works fine when running on my machine at the office but when I port it to the clients terminal server I get this error.

```
System.Net.HttpListenerException (0x80004005): Access is denied
   at System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes()
   at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
   at XeroConnectionTest.clsXeroAuth2.VB$StateMachine_6_oauth2.MoveNext() in Q:\XeroConnectionTest\XeroConnectionTest\clsXeroAuth2.vb:line 21
```

This is the code where it fails

```
    Private callbackurl As String = "http://localhost:5000/signin/"
    
        Public Async Function oauth2() As Task(Of Boolean)
            Dim redirectUri As String = String.Format(callbackurl)
            Dim listener = New HttpListener()
            listener.Prefixes.Add(redirectUri)
    
            Try
                listener.Start()
                stopListening = False
            Catch hlex As HttpListenerException
                'MsgBox(hlex.ToString)
                Form1.TextBox1.Text = hlex.ToString
                Return False
            End Try
```

and the error occurs on listener.start() line.

Any help would be gratefully received

Thanks

Frostie

Comment: When I run the App as Administrator I get the Allow Access page then the Browser displays HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

Comment: Wouldn't 'localhost' normally just be used locally when you're connecting to your own instance? Wouldn't you need a public connection point?

Comment: Andrew I don't think so, I could be wrong, but the users will only be using this locally they won't be outside the office. It works when I run the App as Administrator. I have fixed the 503 error.

Comment: Please note this is a desktop app not a web based one.